# Can a server used for GitLab runners be used as a deployment server?

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I have a relatively simple understanding of GitLab CI:

- There is a GitLab server (server A)
- There is a separate server with GitLab runners (server B)
- And there is some other server - the 'prod' server (server C)

From prior experience, I understand that the GitLab runners would do the following:

- On a push to source control, GitLab (server A) would contact the GitLab runner (server B), and the runner would pull the source control and execute jobs as defined in `.gitlab.ci-yml`, which is included in the source control
- As defined by the `.yml` file, a Docker image would be added back to server A (to the GitLab Docker registry). Then the runner would login to server B, pull the docker image, and start it.

I am opting for a simpler automated deployment setup.. I want 2 servers:

- Server A (GitLab CE)
- Server B: Ubuntu 18 server that has a GitLab runner, AND that serves as a production server

Is this a good idea?

It seems like I can configure the runner to just run a `docker-compose up --rebuild` command, and that this would essentially work.

Is there any reason that I wouldn't want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitLab and GitLab CI are not two servers: they are softwares installed on a server. Now, while both can be installed on the same server, they can be split for scaling reason.

Now your question: it all depends on what type of services your are running. Bear in mind that CI can take CPU/memory and disk bandwidth while running your CI (docker image build, composer, npm, Java, etc.). Doing so can slow down your production server.
Another reason not to run `docker-compose` directly is to avoid downtime: what if there is a mistake during the build or the deployment? Your production will be down. You may want to look at blue/green deployment.

Comment: Thanks. This is case of learning to walk before running. For now, it's okay if the production goes down for a few minutes while deploying. The key thing here is automated deployment via a means that is scalable

Comment: Separate pre-deployment tasks from production. You don't want to jeopardize the later. Today, compute power is cheap...